# VBA, Clear #N/A's from specified Column

Tags: vba

I wish to clear all #N/A's (non formula) from my specified column:

```
Sub ClearNA()

    With Worksheets("database")
    Set rng1 = Range( _
                 Range("A1:FR1").Find("columnname").Offset(1), _
                Range("A1:FR1").Find("columnname").Offset(1).End(xlDown))

    Cells.Replace "#N/A", "", rng1

    End With

End Sub
```

I want to replace them with blanks. I am getting a type mismatch on line

```
Cells.Replace "#N/A", "", rng1
```

**update:**

```
   Sub DeleteStringFromColumn(SearchString As String, _
                               ColumnNameOrNumber As Variant, _
                               MySheet As Worksheet, _
                               Optional ReplaceWith = vbNullString)
    With MySheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, ColumnNameOrNumber), .Cells(1048576, ColumnNameOrNumber)).Replace SearchString, vbNullString
    End With
End Sub


Sub clearNA()

    'DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'ColumnNumber
    DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", "ProductType", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("database") 'ColumnName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped this ask into a small subroutine. See the example sub for usage.

```
Sub DeleteStringFromColumn(SearchString As String, _
                               ColumnNameOrNumber As Variant, _
                               MySheet As Worksheet, _
                               Optional ReplaceWith = vbNullString)
    With MySheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, ColumnNameOrNumber), .Cells(1048576, ColumnNameOrNumber)).Replace SearchString, vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Sub Example()
    DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'ColumnNumber
    DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", "B", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'ColumnName
    DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", ThisWorkbook.Names("ProductType").RefersToRange.Column, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Getting Column Number from Named Range
End Sub
```

Comment: where can I define the column name?  do I just do l `.Range(.Cells(1, 1)` if I want to remove the N/A's from column A?

Comment: See the edit :) You'd call that like `DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", 1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheetNameHere")`

Comment: getting a type mismatch on `.Range(.Cells(1, ColumnNameOrNumber), .Cells(1048576, ColumnNameOrNumber)).Replace SearchString, vbNullString` ill update my code with what I got.

Comment: `ProductType` isn't a valid column reference. It needs to be a number, or letter. Like 1 for Column A, or "B" for Column B. Is `ProductType` a named range? If so something like this would work `DeleteStringFromColumn "#N/A", ThisWorkbook.Names("ProductType").RefersToRange.Column, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped :)